# How to make it end after one decimal but keep two columns?

Tags: decimal

The question is asking us to keep it in two columns not in a row of lines. 
I tried the whole `System.out.printf("%.2f")` but like I said, it makes the numbers come out in a row and not in a column. 
Please try to keep it beginner level because this is only my 2nd CompSci class.

Thank you!

```
System.out.println("Kilograms       Pounds");  
final double pounds = 2.2;

for (int kilo = 1; kilo < 200; kilo += 2){

   System.out.println(kilo + "      " + (kilo*pounds));
   }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question (what is "it"?) and format the contents using the code tags. At the moment it's very hard to read. What are the double slashes for. Are you trying to comment code? That's not necessary. Also add some tags. The language at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to know what you're doing or what you want, but assuming you're using Java 1.5 or later, and assuming you want output like:

```
Kilograms Pounds
1 2.2
3 6.6
5 11.0
...
```

then easiest to stick with `printf` then trying to add formatters to `println`. Just append `\n` to your strings to add new lines. For example:

```
System.out.println("Kilograms Pounds");
final double pounds = 2.2;

for (int kilo = 1; kilo < 200; kilo += 2)
{
    System.out.printf("%d %.1f\n", kilo, kilo*pounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have stated it's not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve based on what you posted but I believe what you want is the output as

```
Kilograms Pounds
1 2
3 6
5 11
7 15
```

Try this:

```
System.out.println(kilo + " " + (int) Math.floor(kilo*pounds)); }
```

It will round your expression then it using the int cast it will cut of the decimal as you state in your question header.